# ssh-copy-id does not work

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to set up a passwordless SSH login on CentOS 5.4:

1. I generated RSA public key on the client.
2. ssh-copy-id from client to server.
3. Verified ~/.ssh/authorized_keys contains the client key.

The client still prompted for password. What did I miss?

Thanks.

EDIT: checked ssh_config and permissions as advised. This is the debug info from the client:

```
debug2: key: /home/saguna/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/saguna/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2b31921be9a0)
debug2: key: /home/saguna/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.1.75.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/saguna/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/saguna/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/saguna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/saguna/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/saguna/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
saguna@192.168.1.75's password:
```

Comment: I get this too :(

Comment: At this point you may have to enable debug mode on the server as well and find out *why* it's rejecting your pubkey offer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was I had RSAAuthentication disbled in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Answer (score 33):

9/10 times it's because ~/.ssh/authorized_keys isn't at the right mode.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures all the file/directory permissions which always caused me headaches...

Comment: If this does not work for someone, you should also  look at @Gilles's answer. In particular, the **home and `~/.ssh`** directories can't be writeable by anyone other than the user.

Comment: I know this is old, but thanks a million to @centic. I was sure my permissions were correct but never bothered to check on the $HOME and .ssh/ directories.

Answer (score 25):

Check in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow authentication with a key. You should have something like this in it, and make sure the lines are not commented:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then restart `sshd` after you modify the file:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: In addition to to Patkos Csaba's answer, check the permissions of your local and remote ~/.ssh folder.

Comment: In my case, `AuthorizedKeysFile` was commented out and I also had to use an absolute path to `authorized_keys`.

Comment: I get 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.' when trying ssh-add

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the comments. The commented out lines show you the default values. You don't need to uncomment them if you want the default value. You only need to uncomment the property if you want to override the default value.

Answer (score 18):

I found that with my system the problem was the user directory (/home/username) was equipped with the wrong permissions set. It was `drwxr-x-w-` and it needed to be `drwxr-xr-x` (with write permission only for the owner). The solution was to use chmod:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /home/username
```

Comment: Yah! Worked for me. ssh was giving me a password prompt because I botched the persmissions.

Comment: Yeah! It has solved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not an expert here but came across such issue too, here are my two cents *in addition* to all the other suggestions.

Sometimes `ssh-copy-id` copies the wrong key to the remote server (may happen if you have several keys and/or are using non-default names for key files) or your authentication agent is misconfigured.

Here's a quote from the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id):

> If the -i option is given then the identity file (defaults to
>   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) is used, regardless of whether there are any keys
>   in your ssh-agent. Otherwise, if this: ssh-add -L provides any output,
>   it uses that in preference to the identity file.

So basically you want to check that:

- Your system authentication agent (usually ssh-agent) sees the keys that you intend to use (check `ssh-add -L` output)

  - If you don't see the desired key, add it using [ssh-add](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)
- The `ssh-copy-id` copied the same key to the remote machine (just log in to the remote server using password and check the contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

  - If you don't see the desired key on the remote server, you can implicitly tell `ssh-copy-id` which key to copy: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/some_public_key`

Hope that helps.

Comment: You nailed it! Digging through _my_ `ssh-copy-id` the problem is: `DEFAULT_PUB_ID_FILE=$(ls -t ${HOME}/.ssh/id*.pub 2>/dev/null | grep -v -- '-cert.pub$' | head -n 1)`, which will default to the alphabetical first key - in my case I had an `id_boot2docker.pub`(which is apparently the default name for boot2docker ssh stuff). Seems like there are a bunch of different ssh-copy-id implementations around; mine came from `brew install ssh-copy-id`, which in turn is taken from openssh-portable. _My_ man page explicitly mentions this behavior...

Answer (score 6):

The most common problem is invalid permissions on the server side. Check that none of your home directory, `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are writable by anyone but you (in particular they must not be group-writable).

If that's not the problem, run `ssh -vvv server` and look at the client's view of the conversation. In particular, check that the client is trying the key with the server.

Comment: Thank you!!! I don't understand why, but **your home directory**, `~/.ssh`, and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` can't be writeable by anyone but you.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to all of the above, one can always check the sshd log file:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: In my case I saw `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/administrator` in this log file which pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to Omer Dagan answer for newer CentOS 7, use:

```
journalctl -f -u sshd
```

for looking at the sshd logs at the server.

Answer (score 2):

I've had that problem on CentOS 7. For me, it turned out to be a problem with SELinux that prevented access to the user's authorized_keys file. I filtered the audit log for the authorized_keys filename and tried to log in from the client machine:

```
[root@centos ssh]# tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log |grep authorized_keys
type=AVC msg=audit(1580206788.877:2649): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=84056 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=74366557 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

First, make sure that semanage is available. On CentOS 7, the required package is policycoreutils-python. You can install it by executing

```
yum -y install policycoreutils-python
```

Afterwards, I updated the context by executing:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t /home/username/.ssh/
restorecon -FRv /home/username/.ssh/
```

...and it finally worked. I found the solution for that here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/849631/why-is-selinux-blocking-remote-ssh-access-without-a-password

https://blog.tinned-software.net/ssh-key-authentication-is-not-working-selinux/

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, answer has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other fixes but found that I had to change the home directory to not be writable by others.
The home directory was 777.
I changed it to 755 and it worked.

Comment: welcome @dulcana, he tries to set a passwrodless ssh login, how changing permisions to 755 could help to solve the problem?

Comment: @FranciscoTapia that's because sshd ensures that other users couldn't have maliciously created the authorized_keys file, refusing login by ssh key where group or other can write the file or any of their parents. Other answers have also mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

full chmod fix from https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key/blob/master/generate-and-send-ssh-key.sh

log in with password / root and switch to the user you want to be able to connect to
then run

```
chmod go-w ~ && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case /etc/ssh/sshd_config contained the following param:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

But ssh-copy-id created a file with name authorized_keys, so I had to modify the entry to the new name. more info about [deprecated authorized_keys2](https://serverfault.com/questions/116177/whats-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-authorized-keys2)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after I deleted the log file on the server and recreated it:

```
rm -rf /var/log/auth.log
nano /var/log/auth.log
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

<kbd>y</kbd>

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

and then

```
ssh-keygen 
(using default options)
ssh-copy-id -i /path-to-public-key user@server
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be referencing the wrong private key. If you have more than one key and a custom key pair (i.e. save the files as `myKey` and `myKey.pub`) then, you need to reference they private key associated to the public key you registered when you ran `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/myKey.pub <username>@<ip-address>`.

In other words, try to run `ssh -i <path-to-key> <username>@<ip-address>`

Answer (score -1):

Easy to overlook this, but if you have an encrypted home directory, it will not work for the first session. Subsequent sessions will however work once the home dir is mounted and the authorized_file is accessible.